# Difference between MaterialPageRoute and PageRouteBuilder

Tags: flutter

To provide custom animations, I can either extend `MaterialPageRoute` or `PageRouteBuilder` and they both seem to do the same job. So, what's the difference between the two and which one should I use?

Here's the code snippet:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, Foo/BarRoute(Scaffold(appBar: AppBar()))),
        child: Text('Navigate'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  final Widget page;
  FooRoute(this.page) : super(builder: (_) => page);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(_, animation, __, ___) {
    return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: page);
  }
}

class BarRoute<T> extends PageRouteBuilder<T> {
  final Widget page;
  BarRoute(this.page) : super(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => page);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(_, animation, __, ___) {
    return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: page);
  }
}
```

The only difference I saw was on running the app on an iOS device where `MaterialPageRoute` tries to insert some iOSed type sliding animation in the background.

Comment: *"To provide custom animations, I can either extend MaterialPageRoute or PageRouteBuilder and [...]"* - actually you hould use [PageTransitionsTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PageTransitionsTheme-class.html)

Comment: @pskink I didn't know about it, thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome, [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1d9032c7e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart#L402) you have some builtin `PageTransitionsBuilder`s

Comment: @pskink If I don't use `PageTransitionsTheme` but directly use `PageTransitionsBuilder.buildTransitions` in overridden `buildTransitions()` method, it works when extending `PageRouteBuilder` but has the iOSed type navigation for `MaterialPageRoute` as I mentioned in the question. Is there any other way of doing it without providing `PageTransitionsTheme` to the `MaterialApp`. I hope you get what I was trying to say.

Comment: *"Is there any other way of doing it without providing PageTransitionsTheme to the MaterialApp"* - i dont know, btw why dont you want to use `PageTransitionsTheme`?

Comment: @pskink Well, it isn't like I don't want to use the `PageTransitionsTheme`, I just wanted to know if there's some other way, and if you don't know that, it probably means there's no way!

Comment: *"and if you don't know that, it probably means there's no way!"* - not at all - if `PageTransitionsTheme` can do that it means it is possible - just take a look into the sources